# I want to rewrite all slugs using my post title or name -- wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-controls, password-protection

[image]

I am was using another software from I have migrated all data with randomly generated slug but that slug is not working for search. there also Product title includes my local language. I to run urlencode function for regenerate perfect slug but how can I do that?

Comment: You want to have slug based on title with the language of the same that is shown above the screenshot.

Comment: yes, sir, I want to rewrite al of theme